# device_detail() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk' (Updated)

Tags: django

I am currently encountering this issue now  **The current path, device/{℅ url 'device-detail' form.instance.pk %}, didn’t match any of these** I cant seem to get past this error

My codes:

urls.py

```
path('device/device_detail/<int:pk>/', views.device_detail, name='device-detail'),
```

views.py

```
def device_detail(request, pk):
    device = Device.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'interface/device_detail.html',{'devices':device})
```

device.html

```
<a href="{℅ url 'device-detail' form.instance.pk %}" class="action-icon"> <i
                                                    class="mdi mdi-square-edit-outline"></i></a>
```

device_detail.html

```
{% extends "interface/base.html" %}
{% block footer_scripts %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <script>
    // additional javascript
    </script>
{% endblock footer_scripts %}
{% block content %}
                <div class="content-page">
                    <div class="content">
                        
                        <!-- start page title -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="page-title-box">
                                    <!--<div class="page-title-right">
                                        <ol class="breadcrumb m-0">
                                            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="javascript: void(0);">Hyper</a></li>
                                            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="javascript: void(0);">eCommerce</a></li>
                                            <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Devices</li>
                                        </ol>
                                    </div>
                                -->
                                    <h4 class="page-title">Edit device</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>     
                        <!-- end page title --> 

                        <div class="row">
                            <form action="device/device_detail/<int:pk>" method="post">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <table>
                                {{form.as_table}}
                             </table>
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <!-- end row -->
                    </div> <!-- End Content -->
{% endblock content %}
```

So now im linking the device.html to device_detail.html thru the button

Comment: Please add your request with detail. Which url you are requesting for example

Comment: What do u mean by that? I thought im requesting for the html with 'devices' as device?

Comment: You request to a url, not a html page. in here, your both urls are rendering same template and i can't get why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `device_detail` view is expecting an arg `pk` but you are not passing  arg `pk` through your `url`. Just pass the arg through `url` i,e: edit your url of `device_detail` like below:

```
path('device/device_detail/<int:pk>', views.device_detail, name='device-detail')
```

check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial03/) documentation for more details

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this actually but it doesnt work due to the path not found. Im thinking its the html now. May I asked how to type for the html. Now it is <form action="device/device_detail/<int:pk>" method="post"> and it doesnt work – Calvin Lin just now   Edit   Delete

Comment: In your form action, add url and pass the id of form instance like this: `{℅ url 'device-detail' form.instance.pk %}` and what do you mean by `path` not found? Please add the traceback with op.

Comment: I say wrongly about the path but with ur code i added in html under the button. The path this time got issue. I got this **The current path, device/{℅ url 'device-detail' form.instance.pk %}, didn’t match any of these.**. I have edit the post with the current codes

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are requesting to second url, means : `path('device/device_detail/', views.device_detail, name='device-detail'),`

Problem is that you hadn't declared `<int:pk>` in url path, then in your view, `device_detail`, it can't get what is `pk`:

```py
path('device/device_detail/<int:pk>/', views.device_detail),
```

Then you can send a request to url like: `device/device_detail/1/`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this actually but it doesnt work due to the path not found. Im thinking its the html now. May I asked how to type for the html. Now it is <form action="device/device_detail/<int:pk>" method="post"> and it doesnt work